# roscpp client fails to call rospy service

Tags: python, c++, ros, rospy

I am trying to use a roscpp client to call a rospy server. Unfortunately, my calls from my client always fail even though my server appears to be running correctly and without issue. I have included the code for the client and server below along with the output I receive (I can include the CMakeList.txt and package.xml upon request but I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the following files).

service.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from std_srvs.srv import Empty, EmptyResponse
import rospy

def serviceCall(call):
    print "service called"
    return EmptyResponse()

def serviceCall_server():
    rospy.init_node('service_server')
    s = rospy.Service('a_new_service', Empty, serviceCall)
    print "Ready to receive service calls."
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serviceCall_server()
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_srvs/Empty.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "service_client");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Rate r(30);

    ros::ServiceClient service_call = n.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/a_new_service", 100);

    std_srvs::Empty srv;
    service_call.waitForExistence();
    if (service_call.call(srv))
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Successfully called service a_new_service");
    }
    else
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service a_new_service");
    }

}
```

launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="server" pkg="test" type="server.py" output="screen"/>
    <node name="client" pkg="test" type="client" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

output from launch file:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[server-1]: started with pid [25659]
process[client-2]: started with pid [25660]
[ INFO] [1485448779.402439557]: waitForService: Service [/a_new_service] has not been advertised, waiting...
Ready to receive service calls.
[ INFO] [1485448779.630636002]: waitForService: Service [/a_new_service] is now available.
[ERROR] [1485448779.630685730]: Failed to call service a_new_service
```

Running the launch file causes the service call to fail (see the last line of the output). I can call **rosservice call /a_new_service  {}** from the terminal successfully which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong with my client but I am unsure what is wrong.

--

EDIT: So upon further investigation this seems to be a fault with the launch file Since I am able to call both the server and client using rosrun and have them communicate successfully. Does anyone have any idea why the launch file would cause an error with the call? Especially considering the fact that the waitForService call says the server is available.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve my own problem by changing

```
ros::ServiceClient service_call = n.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/a_new_service", 100);
```

into

```
ros::ServiceClient service_call = n.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/a_new_service");
```

I'm still not entirely sure why the code let me compile with this as I cannot see any information on the ROS API as to what the value could have meant.